# How to download files from a web based file server with Python Mechanize

Tags: python, download, mechanize

I have a series of files on a private ftp file server that I am trying to download using mechanize.

The mechanize link objects have the structure

```
Link(base_url='http://myfileserver.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi', url='index.cgi?page=download&file=%2Fhome%2Fjmyfileserver%2Fpublic_html%2Fuser_data%2Fmycompany%2F.ftpquota', text='Download [IMG]', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'index.cgi?page=download&file=%2Fhome%2Fjmyfileserver%2Fpublic_html%2Fuser_data%2Fmycompany%2F.ftpquota'), ('class', 'ar')])
```

This basically corresponds to a link where a file icon is linked to the file

I am new to mechanize.
But how do I download the linked file  can be got from

```
urlparse.urljoin(base_url , url)
```

Which combines the two to get :

```
http://myfileserver.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi?page=download&file=%2Fhome%2Fjmyfileserver%2Fpublic_html%2Fuser_data%2Fmycompany%2F.ftpquota
```

I dont know how to proceed.

My raw code

```
import mechanize
import subprocess
import urlparse
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://myfileserver.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['login'] = "mylogin"
br['password'] = "mypassword"
br.submit()
#print dir(br)
myfiles = []
for alink in br.links():
    print alink
    myfiles.append(alink)

def downloadlink(l):
    print " Trying to download", l.url.split("%2F")[-1]
    f=open(l.url.split("%2F")[-1],"w") 
    myurl = urlparse.urljoin(l.base_url,l.url)
    print myurl
    # Dont know how to proceed



for linkobj in myfiles:

    if "sca" in linkobj.url:
        #br.follow_link(text='[IMG]', nr=0)
        downloadlink(linkobj)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with:

```
for index, linkobj in enumerate(myfiles):
    if "sca" in linkobj.url:
        resp = br.follow_link(text='Download [IMG]',nr=0)
        content = resp.read()
        with open('output%s.txt' % index, 'w') as fo:
           fo.write(content)
```

Comment: When I try this the file written to my directory is basically the html code for the login form . So it does not have the files liked to by these links.

Comment: @har that's because `text='[IMG]'` is not probably working. You should point to the correct download link (that I can't guess) and it should work

Comment: Awesome Awesome . That worked. I was literally putting the text='[IMG]' to get it to work. Once I changed that to `resp = br.follow_link(text='Download [IMG]',nr=0)` The code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ftp server, mechanize is not the way to download your file, you should look at [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html). This [tutorial](http://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm) should get you on your way.

Comment: Its not an ftp server. But a cgi frontend meant for http based manual file download that I want to automate. Especially when there are tens of files : it gets painful to click the save file as link one by one